# If VBA generates any errors, have macro write "Unknown Error" into ErrorMsg string variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a global variable `ErrorMsg As String` that saves all my possible known error messages that could arise in my code. However, I am looking for a way to have the macro write `ErrorMsg = MsgBox "Unknown Error" if a VBA generated error occurs or an unexpected error comes up. Is there a way to add a generic line that says if an error appears make` ErrorMsg = MsgBox "Unknown Error"`

```
Global Parameter As Long, RoutingStep As Long, wsName As String, ErrorMsg As String, SectionName As String, SDtab As Worksheet, subsysnum As String
Global wb As Workbook, sysrow As Long, sysnum As String, ws As Worksheet
Global center_wavelength_value As Double, sweeprate_value As Double

Public Sub Main()
Dim syswaiver As Long, axsunpart As Long
Dim startcell As String, cell As Range
Dim syscol As Long, dict As Object, wbSrc As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks("SD093_KW.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data Sheet") 

syswaiver = GetColumnIndex(ws, "System Waiver Number(s)")
axsunpart = GetColumnIndex(ws, "Part Number")

Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("Q:\Documents\Specification Document.xlsx")
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") 

If Not syswaiver = 0 Then
    startcell = ws.cells(2, syswaiver).Address 
Else
    ErrorMsg = "System waiver number column index not found. Value needed to proceed"
    GoTo Skip
End If

For Each cell In ws.Range(startcell, ws.cells(ws.Rows.Count, syswaiver).End(xlUp)).cells 
sysnum = cell.value
sysrow = cell.row
syscol = cell.column

If Not dict.Exists(sysnum) Then 
    dict.Add sysnum, True

    If Not SheetExists(sysnum, wb) Then 
        If Not axsunpart = 0 Then
            wsName = cell.EntireRow.Columns(axsunpart).value 
            If SheetExists(wsName, wbSrc) Then 
                wbSrc.Worksheets(wsName).copy After:=ws 
                wb.Worksheets(wsName).Name = sysnum 
            Set SDtab = wb.Worksheets(ws.Index + 1) 
            Else
                ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", "") & "Axsun part number for " & sysnum & " sheet to be copied could not be copied"
                cell.Interior.Color = vbRed '
            GoTo Skip
            End If
            
SDTabHeaders

Sheets(1).Select 

' Power Section
Power

Skip:
Dim begincell As Long
With logsht ' wb.Worksheets("Log Sheet")
    begincell = .cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    .cells(begincell + 1, 3).value = sysnum
    .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Font.Bold = True
    .cells(begincell + 1, 2).value = Date
    .cells(begincell + 1, 2).Font.Bold = True
    If Not ErrorMsg = "" Then
        .cells(begincell + 1, 4).value = vbNewLine & "Complete with Erorr - " & vbNewLine & ErrorMsg
        .cells(begincell + 1, 4).Font.Bold = True
        .cells(begincell + 1, 4).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Else
        .cells(begincell + 1, 4).value = "All Sections Completed without Errors"
        .cells(begincell + 1, 4).Font.Bold = True
        .cells(begincell + 1, 4).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End If
End With
Next cell
End Sub
```

---

```
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, wb As Workbook) 
If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0 
End Function
```

---

```
Sub SDTabHeaders()
SectionName = "SD Tab Headers"
On Error GoTo errormessage
    Parameter = GetColumnIndex(SDtab, "PARAMETER")
    RoutingStep = GetColumnIndex(SDtab, "Routing Step 1")
    specmin = GetColumnIndex(SDtab, "SPEC min")
    specmax = GetColumnIndex(SDtab, "SPEC max")

errormessage:
    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Power()
Dim power_col As Long, power_value As Double, power_rowindex As Double
SectionName = "Power"
On Error GoTo errormessage
power_col = GetColumnIndex(ws, "Average Power (mW)")
power_value = Getdata(ws, sysrow, power_col)

errormessage:
    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg
End Sub
```

---

```
Function GetColumnIndex(sht As Worksheet, colname As String) As Double 
Dim paramname As Range
Set paramname = sht.Range("A1", sht.cells(2, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).cells.Find(What:=colname, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True) 
    If Not paramname Is Nothing Then 
        GetColumnIndex = paramname.column
    ElseIf paramname Is Nothing Then
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", "") & SectionName & ": " & colname & "column index could not be found" & vbNewLine 
    End If
End Function
```

---

```
Function Getdata(sht As Worksheet, WDrow As Long, parametercol As Long) As Variant ' locates the cell with the jira data
Getdata = sht.cells(WDrow, parametercol)
If Getdata < 0 Or GetJIRAdata = Empty Then
    ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", "") & SectionName & ": " & "data could not be found" & vbNewLine 
End If
End Function
```

Comment: You are already using ON ERROR GOTO...What else do you need?

Comment: @NoChance I am looking to see if there is a way to say unknown error if an error that I do not anticipate occurring.

Comment: You could capture the error code and check it against this list: https://chejunkie.com/knowledge-base/common-runtime-error-codes-vba/

Comment: @NoChance So write `On Error GoTo 0` at the beginning and then at the end of the sub write `Err.Raise`

Comment: Yes, in the global error handler you can tell what error has occurred. Most of the time, you can do little about it....See the  example here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement#example